# How to use Add-Migration if the project contains multiple folders

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

I would like to `Add-Migration` with my DbContext, but I get Error:

`The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Is the problem related with folder structure? The customized User.cs, Role.cs and the Startup.cs are in different folders.

[image]

The Entity Framework is included in the DbContext project file.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is your project asp.net core or asp.net framework? According to your last pic, the packages are not loaded successfully.(See the yellow warnings). And the `add-migration` can't be recognized unless your Microsoft.EntifyFrameworkCore packages is installed well. Try restore the packages to check if it resolves the warnings, if not, share the info about what you get in View=>Error List.  Also, it all packages are installed well, you can try installing the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package, clean the cache and restart VS to make the add-migration command work,

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT It shows pic 1 if I open the whole project folder, i got yellow warnings when I open `ReactTemplate.Infrastructure` project only, after I added EF.tools, I got result "Build Failed"

Comment: Does it build successfully before adding the EF.Tools package? As I know, simply add a package won't cause build errors unless it's not compatible with your project. But you're in a asp.net core project, and this package is compatible with .net core2.2, so it won't be the cause of your build error.

Comment: I think your original issue `The term 'add-migration' is not recognized` and build error after consuming the EF.Tools packages all result from the yellow warnings in pic2. Those warnings may indicate the packages are not found or loaded well. And you can get info about them from View=>Error List. If possible, create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it by github or one-drive here, so that I can check it directly for you. Or share more details about your project type, framework, info in Error List...

Answer (score 1):

> Is the problem related with folder structure?

This issue is not about the `folder structure`.It's about the `nuget packages` and you project's `target framework`.

Nuget packages can bring the part of `EF framework` to you. Just like `Microsoft Unit Test` framework, we have to consume the `MSTest.TestFramework` and `MSTest.TestAdapter` packages in the project to make the `test framework` work well.

As for your issue, the original cause can be that **those packages are not loaded or incompatible** in your current project.(Yellow warnings in pic 2).

Resolve the yellow warnings and install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` packages, then the command should work. See:

[image]

Red warnings in pic occurred before I install that two packages. After install them **successfully**, the command can be recognized well by current project.

**Suggestions:**

If you're not that familiar with how to resolve nuget issues(yellow warnings), share more details about it, your VS version, target framework, error messgae in Error List window...

And also I suggest you can create a new `Asp.net core web app` to test it, do nothing but install those two packages successfully, then the **Add-migration** command can be recognized by your new project. Then you can confirm if something wrong with nuget packages in your current project that causes the issue, like what I said above.

Hope it makes some help :)