# Abp 5.0 Template Issue with EF on VS2017

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, nuget, aspnetboilerplate

everyone,
I downloaded the template with the following features

- Abp 5.0.0.0
- Asp.Net MVC 5.x
- Web application with server rendered HTML; ASP.NET MVC & jQuery
- Entity Framework

VS2017 Community as Development Environment

The problem lies in the Entity Framework or the version of Nuget
Running the Update-Database command from the Nuget console always returns the same error

***Update-Database not recognized cmdlet***

My Nuget Version is 4.9.3.5777

I tried both to clear nuget cache, restore solution packages, restart vs2017 and computer (Windows 7 Enterprise 64) without success

There is some issue on download packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is some issue on download packages?

I think this issue stands that the [EF package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.4.0-preview3-19553-01) is not installed successfully in your current project.

1.Please check if you have yellow warnings in Solution Explorer like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093181/how-to-use-add-migration-if-the-project-contains-multiple-folders). If there's any warning, resolve it or share it here and I'll check it for you.

2.I know you've cleaned the nuget cache, but see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders), there's one copy of the `EF package` locates in your `Solution folder`'s `packages` folder when you're in project that uses `Packages.config` format. So though you've cleaned the nuget cache in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`, your project is **still using the old copy** in `solutionDirectory\packages` folder.

**Suggestion**(The order is important, please follow the steps one by one):

#1 For this, you should right-click your project=>Manage Nuget Packages(UI)=>Uninstall the `EntityFramework` package.(Or manually delete the EF package folder within `SolutionDir\packages` folder)

#2 Then clean the nuget cache by `Tools=>Nuget Package Manager=>Package Manager Settings=>Clear All Nuget Cache`.

#3 Close [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell#opening-the-console-and-console-controls) if it's open. => Close VS instance.

#4 Then restart VS and reinstall that EF package by package manager UI. And manually open the Package Manager Console and type `Update-Database` to check if this issue goes away.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Hi Lance LI-MSFT ,
now works properly.
I have executed your suggested  steps :))